# How to attach event for all elements with a specifit attribute with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have dynamic input text in my page that contains a attribute `clientid=1` , `clientid=2` etc..

Is is possible to associate a keypress event for any textbox containing this clientid? how?

note:
not all text box have the attribute which means they shouldn't have keypress

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Use .keypress() with .on() and selector like as $('input[clientid]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [has-attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for event delegation:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[type="text"][clientid]', function(e) {
    // your code here
});
```

Event delegation will react to elements that are added after the page has loaded (and the code has executed). Ideally, rather than using `document`, you'd specify a selector for an element that does exist when the page loads, will always exist, and that will contain all of the elements you want to react to the `keypress` event.

Comment: @kicaj Edited, missed that in the question.

Comment: I think is better If You comment own post with fix, not editing, this is my opinion

Comment: @kicaj Adding additional information in comments is the absolute incorrect approach. All of the relevant information should be contained in the question or answer so people don't also have to read through comments to find it - this is precisely **why** questions and answers are always editable.

Comment: nice, +1 before I accept, is "e" the input text object as argument? cuz I can't get the val() from e..

Comment: @ThePoet No, `e` is the event object. The element triggering the event (the text box) can be referenced inside that function using `this`, so `this.value`. You can also use `$(this).val()`, but I'd avoid creating a jQuery object out of the DOM node reference unless you're going to need it for things you can't access directly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(':input[clientid]').on('keypress',function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute selector to match your textboxes:

```
$('input[type="text"][clientid]')
```

Also, rename your custom attribute to `data-clientid`.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes.** You can use:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[clientid]', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Or for more specific targetting:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[clientid="1"]', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, for that you can use the new `on`.